# scheduled send mail task in SSIS

Tags: email, ssis, task, send

I have created a package in SSIS  to fetch data from SQL Server table, then stored the result into an Excel destinationand and created a send email task .

How can i schedule the package to run automatically ?   for example , every sunday at 11am ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it out and run it in a sql job, then schedule the job for the day(s) and time(s) you need.